# how to combine multiple header in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

[image]I want to Combine these two column "Stakes" and "Game".

I want to combine two column into one column using wpf datagrid.

My DataGrid is as Follow.![enter image description here][2]
![enter image description here][3]

```
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Color="#FF000000" Direction="-60" Opacity="0.32" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#404040"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="DataContext">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}">
                                    <TextBlock.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Color="#FF000000" Direction="-60" Opacity="0.32" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                    </TextBlock.Effect>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <DataGrid.RowBackground >
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/ClientApplication;component/Images/second_row_bg.png"/>
                </DataGrid.RowBackground>
                <DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/ClientApplication;component/Images/bonus_progress_bg.png"/>
                </DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground>



                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">



                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}">
                                        <TextBlock.Effect>
                                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Color="#FF000000" Direction="-60" Opacity="0.32" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                        </TextBlock.Effect>
                                    </TextBlock>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/ClientApplication;component/Images/table_bg_header.png"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush   ImageSource="/ClientApplication;component/Images/titel_bg.png"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#404040" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 0, 1, 0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="26" />
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>







                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>



                <DataGrid.Columns>


                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="125" Header="Table" Binding="{Binding Path=Table}">

                    </DataGridTextColumn>





                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="102"   Header="Stakes" Binding="{Binding Path=Stakes}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="95" Header="Game" Binding="{Binding Path=Game}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="87" Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="83" Header="Players" Binding="{Binding Path=Players}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="117" Header="Average Pot" Binding="{Binding Path=Average}"   />
                    <DataGridTextColumn  Width="65" Header="H/Hr" Binding="{Binding Path=hhr}"  />
                </DataGrid.Columns>



            </DataGrid>
```

Please give me important comment on this. 
Thanks For your help.

Comment: why dont you create single column that has data template for both column?

Comment: Can You please tell me How to do it  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you`re ok with making it read-only, then the easy way is to have one more property to bind to - `StakesAndGame`:

```
public string StakesAndGame
{
   get { return string.Format("{0}   {1}", Stakes, Game); }
}
```

and just add column that uses it:

```
<DataGridTextColumn  Width="102" Header="Stakes" Binding="{Binding StakesAndGame}"  />
```

Just don`t forget to call `OnPropertyChanged` for that property as well when Stakes or Game change. Or you can write a value converter and combine two columns together with it, but it requires more coding than previous one.

If you need them to be writable, then it`s harder and I really don`t recommend such approach. But if you need it anyway, you could play with `DataGridTemplateColumn` like in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6961296/1021555).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` to do what you want:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Stakes">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Stakes}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Game}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```