# Make some of DataGrid cells span multiple columns

Tags: c#, wpf

OK, I have searched for pretty long time for solution of this problem. I am developing simple printing system for WPF DataGrids and have managed to print tables with uniform cell placement using DataTable and setting it as DataGrid's ItemSource.

However, I needed **some** rows to **contain only one cell** (you can think of it like "row group header" inside the table).

So, since I haven't found anything about DataTable's cells spanning multiple columns (if this can be made, it would be a great thing to know how), I figured I would have to add rows to DataGrid manually, and solve it something like this:

- Make new DataGrid with desired columns
- Add rows one by one, setting the DataGridCellPanel that spans or not spans through rows

The second point is where I have the problem (if it's right, that is). I need to **add row** to a DataGrid that uses **simple array of strings as cell data** (index in array should mach the cell index). Is there an easy way to do something like that?

Comment: Here s how I did it entirely in XAML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38687666/3360864

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after some more fiddling with all this, I have reached a very nice solution.

The best and easiest thing to do is to apply a data template to particular rows after the DataGrid is loaded. So, I stuck to original idea with DataTables and remembered the indices that needed to have their template changed. I just took the DataGridRows from these indices and applied the template that had custom made ItemsPanelTemplate that spans multiple columns.

EDIT: On Daniel's request, I'm including some code.

First thing we need is a template for spanning row:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType='{x:Type DataGridRow}'
                 xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                 xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
    <Border>
        <DataGridCellsPresenter Foreground='Black'>
            <DataGridCellsPresenter.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <local:DataGridSpannedCellPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </DataGridCellsPresenter.ItemsPanel>
        </DataGridCellsPresenter>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

NOTE: local:DataGridSpannedCellPanel is a custom DataGridCellsPanel with overridden ArrangeOverride method that makes first cell span entire size.

You can make a string in code-behind and load your template from it, for example.
The next thing is creating your grid and initializing some of the rows with this new template:

```
var newGrid = MakeNewDataGrid();
newGrid.ItemsSource = myTable.AsDataView();
var template = XamlReader.Parse(HeaderRowTemplate) as ControlTemplate;

foreach (int index in myHeaderIndices)
{
    var container = newGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    var row = container as DataGridRow;
    if (row != null)
    {
        row.Template = template;
    }
}
```

Also note, rows in your table need to be made as follows:

```
if (bindableQuote.IsGroup())
{
    table.Rows.Add("Header");
}
else
{
    table.Rows.Add(rowData.ToArray());
}
```

That's about it, the only thing left is to figure out how to implement DataGridSpannedCellPanel.

Comment: Can you provide a stripped down example for that?

Comment: Please see edited response. I will be glad to answer any questions you may have.

Comment: @DejanMaksimovic: did you figure out how to implement DataGridSpannedCellPanel? If yes can you post the code or the important parts? Thanks.

Comment: @RobotMess: I think posting additional code would really exceed the question's scope, but you should just extend DataGridCellsPanel and override ArrangeOverride(Size availableSize) method. Then call Arrange(rect) on first child in Children collection with availableSize. Arrange the rest of children with zero rects.

Comment: @DejanMaksimovic: Thanks, I did manage to figure it out after a while. I just needed to call child.Arrange(rectThatIncludesSpanWidth) for the cell that spans, and child.Arrange(new Rect(0,0,0,0)) for the cells that are hidden.

Comment: Interesting solution, I'll have to give this one a try. Thank you.

Comment: @DejanMaksimovic: I Tried this but its not working. it still resizes my column header width. please help me here. I can show my impl/code if you want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31676437/make-specific-of-datagrid-cell-span-multiple-columns