# Make specific of DataGrid cell span multiple columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I referred this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470860/make-some-of-datagrid-cells-span-multiple-columns) but Its not working. Column still expands to the Row content. Column size is somehow gets updated when cell is re-arranged

Screenshot: [image: ColumnSpan Issue]

My custom `DataGridCellsPanel.ArrangeOverride`:

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
{
    var firstCell = Children[0];
    firstCell.SetValue(Panel.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    firstCell.Arrange(new Rect(arrangeSize));

    for (int i = 1; i < Children.Count; i++)
    {
        var remainingCell = Children[i];
        remainingCell.Arrange(new Rect(0,0,0,0));
    }
    return arrangeSize;
}
```

My `DataGridRow.Template`:

```
<Style x:Key="SpanRowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border>
                    <DataGridCellsPresenter Foreground="Black">
                        <DataGridCellsPresenter.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <controls:DataGridSpannedCellPanel/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </DataGridCellsPresenter.ItemsPanel>
                    </DataGridCellsPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Please help.

Comment: Can't really tell in the screenshot if that's spanning multiple columns or not; is it working in that example or not; would help to show what you have and what you're trying to do next time.  Your verbiage makes the question confusing.  This looks like a prime example for `DataGrid` and using its RowDetails feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. :)

Setting ColumnWidth to Auto was the culprit. setting it to static values worked fine.